# WPF schedule control

Tags: wpf, controls, scheduler

I'm looking for a very simple schedule control for WPF.
What I need is something like daypilot or the Outlook scheduler but with minimal functionality.
I simply want to show a day separated in 24 interval (one for each hour). Inside these 24 hours, the user has to define events/task, non-overlapping each other. That's for theory.
Practically, I want to write a control where the user can define inside a day and for each day a week, how much a kWh of electricity costs.

I found a lot of samples, but most of them are very complex, or simply doesn't work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my original CodeProject article

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar2.aspx

And here is my remake

- http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/timeslotpanel/
- http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/who%E2%80%99s-the-boss/

Comment: What is the difference between the original and the remake?

Comment: Mainly support for Silverlight and WPF with the same code base!

Comment: @rudigrobler I know this is ancient, but can you provide a link to the source from your latest articles?

Answer (score 0):

codeplex has open source schedule control, see http://wpfschedule.codeplex.com/ But it has only daily view.