# How to convert Silverlight Projects or controls to WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, scheduler, persian

There is no Persian Scheduler for WPF. I have found one which is in SilverLoght but not in WPF How can I convert it? I have full access to the SL source code

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to simply try.

Create a WPF project and add the code to find out if there is anything preventing you from this migration.

(Make sure you have the actual rights to do so (copyright etc.))

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to find a [alternative WPF scheduler control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042478/wpf-schedule-control).

You can follow [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to see the differences between WPF and SL.